# Где сейчас найти фикс для unexpected precompiled header error в VS 2008?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

При сборке проекта возникает `unexpected precompiled header error, simply rerunning the compiler might fix this problem`.

В [данном вопросе](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11854470/11790859) советуют скачать фикс для VS 2008 по [ссылке](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=25785). Т.к. ответ старый, ссылка недействительна и перенаправляется на страницу **Microsoft Connect Has Been Retired**.

Вопрос: где теперь взять данный фикс?

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/11854470/11790859

Answer (score 0):

Благодаря [@dIm0n](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/398802/dim0n) ответ был найден в комментарии [@JacobSeleznev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115272/jacob-seleznev) к тому же вопросу (добавлен к вопросу в качестве ассоциации).

**Ответ: по [данной ссылке](http://thehotfixshare.net/board/index.php?autocom=downloads&showfile=11640) находится файл с фиксом, установка которого действительно исправляет проблему.**

Comment: Реально? Мы прям все сейчас побежим качать "файлы" (вируса) из файлопомойки.

Comment: @outoftime Не хотите – не качайте. Ваше дело. Данный ресурс был предложен в аналогичном вопросе на EnSO, комментарий набрал 18 голосов. Плюс, на сайте Microsoft советуют качать именно этот файл (не с данного ресурса, но всё же именно этот фикс). Если Вы боитесь скачать файл с обменника из-за неких мнимых "вирусов", я Вам не завидую. В любом случае, предложите лучшее решение данной проблемы или не принижайте достоинства этого.

Comment: Вы из числа тех, кто пойдёт прыгать с моста, раз все прыгают. Я верно понял?

Comment: @outoftime Я из числа тех, кто доверяет SO, как лучшему ресурсу для решения подобных проблем. Если бы данный файл был вредоносным, на комментарий давно прилетели бы жалобы и он был бы удалён. Вы недооцениваете SO.

Comment: @outoftime Тем более, я лично установил данный фикс и ничего, кроме решения проблемы, он мне не принёс.